# Change other file inside EventStream of other gulp

Tags: gulp

I have one interesting question. Is it possible to change some file inside open stream (EventStream) inside gulp?

I have that stuff. I want to read some file inside opened stream and write that stuff to other file. How I can do it? Thanks.

```
gulp.task('handleGlobalStorage', function () {
  return gulp.src('./global_storage.js')
    .pipe(setEnvHostAndProxy())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./built'));
});

function setEnvHostAndProxy() {
  return es.map(function(file, cb) {
     var fileContent = file.contents.toString();
     //some changes inside content
     // if (!gutil.env.dev) return;
     /* I have stuff that fetched from file and I modify it that I send it 
        down to pipe. But also I want to insert this stuff inside other 
        file. How I can do it? Should I create WritableStream of that file    
        and merge it ?*/
     file.contents = new Buffer(fileContent);
     // send the updated file down the pipe
     cb(null, file);
  });
}
```

Comment: You need to be more specific. Does that other file already exist or do you just want to create a new file from scratch? Do you want to write the other file to the `./built` folder as well or somewhere else?

Comment: Thanks Sven for answer. Actually file exists, and I just want to change it without importing them, but main strem should be imported.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved that issue, here is solution (I will not show all code, only general). The main concept is - open file and write new stuff inside pipe :) that's all.

```
function setEnvHostAndProxy() {
        var bsConfigFileContent = fs.readFileSync('./bs-config.js', 'utf8'),
            bsConfigProxyPattern = /(proxyUrl\s?=\s?)["|'](.*)["|']/;

    return es.map(function (file, cb) {
        var fileContent = file.contents.toString(),
            prodHost = fileContent.match(generateRegExpForHosts('prodHost'))[1],
            prodProxy = fileContent.match(generateRegExpForHosts('prodProxy'))[1],
            devProxy = fileContent.match(generateRegExpForHosts('devProxy'))[1],
            devHost = fileContent.match(generateRegExpForHosts('devHost'))[1],
            changedBsConfigFileStream,
            res;

        if (!gutil.env.dev) {
           res = prodHandler();
            changedBsConfigFileStream = bsConfigHandler(prodHost);
        } else {
            res = devHandler();
            changedBsConfigFileStream = bsConfigHandler(devProxy);
        }

        fs.writeFile('./bs-config.js', changedBsConfigFileStream, 'utf8', function (err) {
            if (err) throw (err);
        });

        file.contents = new Buffer(res);

        cb(null, file);
} });
```